# Compiler warns me that binding will not work but why I run the application it does work!

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, adobe

The Flex application below generates the compiler warning: *Data binding will not be able to detect assignments to 'dp'*. This seems correct since the variable 'dp' is not a bindable property (there is no [Bindable] metadata tag). I have added a button which appends items to the back of 'dp' when it is clicked. Although the compiler warns me that I will not see changes to 'dp', the list shows the new item every time the button is clicked!

I do not understand why I can see new items appear in the list. Can someone explain why this still works although 'dp' is not bindable?

```
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="vertical" minWidth="955" minHeight="600">
<mx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import mx.collections.ArrayCollection;
        import mx.rpc.events.ResultEvent;

        private var arrayData:Array = [
            {name:"banana", cat:"fruit", cost:0.99},
            {name:"bread", cat:"bakery", cost:1.99},
            {name:"orange", cat:"fruit", cost:0.52},
            {name:"donut", cat:"bakery", cost:0.33},
            {name:"apple", cat:"fruit", cost:1.05}];

        private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(arrayData);

        private function onButtonClick(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            var obj:Object = new Object();
            obj.name="test";
            obj.cat="testcat";
            obj.cost=666;
            dp.addItem(obj);
        }
    ]]>
</mx:Script>        
<mx:HorizontalList dataProvider="{dp}" labelField="name" columnWidth="100" width="80%" height="50"/>
<mx:Button label="Click me" click="onButtonClick(event)" />
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compiler is correct in it's warning.

The compiler is warning you that assignments that change the value of `dp` from the initial `ArrayCollection` you specified to another `ArrayCollection` won't be detected.

However, if you leave the value of `dp` alone, and only change the contents of it, then your `<HorizontalList />` will continue to work.

This may seem trivial, but it's an important distinction, and one that can lead to some very confusing bugs further down the road in your application.

Assignments to the variable `dp` will not be detected.  However, changes to the `ArrayCollection`s `list` will, because they dispatch a `CollectionChangeEvent`.

eg:

```
private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection();

private function test():void
{
    // Here, we don't change the value of dp directly,
    // instead we just modify it's list.
    // The DataGroup will show the strings One,Two
    dp.addItem("One")
    dp.addItem("Two") 

    // Here, we change the actual value of dp, by assigning a 
    // new ArrayCollection to it.
    // This change would not be detected, and the list would continue to show 
    // the contents of the previous value.
    // Additionally, the label will show the string "Length: 2",
    // even though the length is clearly now 3. 
    dp = new ArrayCollection(); 
    dp.addItem("Tahi");
    dp.addItem("Rua");
    dp.addItem("Toru");
}


<s:DataGroup dataProvider="{dp}" />
<s:Label text="Length: {dp.length}" />
```

Comment: Rather confusing 'cause it seems that even the official Adobe documentation marks ArrayCollection variables as bindable where it clearly is redundant or unnecessary.

Comment: Actually, it's not redundant - it's really important.  I've modified my answer to try to clarify what's going on.  Debugging Bindings is a pain, so take heed of the warnings that the compiler issues you.

Comment: +1 for not redundant.

If you know that the value *is not* gonna change, you should use *const* instead of *var* in the declaration of dp. The warning should go away (at least, it works with Flex 4.5 compiler).

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
[Bindable("__NoChangeEvent__")]
private var dp:ArrayCollection = new ArrayCollection(arrayData);
```

What about adding elements in list see the code of `ListBase`:

```
public function set dataProvider(value:Object):void
{
    if (collection)
    {
        collection.removeEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, collectionChangeHandler);
    }

    if (value is Array)
    {
        collection = new ArrayCollection(value as Array);
    }
    else if (value is ICollectionView)
    {
        collection = ICollectionView(value);
    }
    else if (value is IList)
    {
        collection = new ListCollectionView(IList(value));
    }
    else if (value is XMLList)
    {
        collection = new XMLListCollection(value as XMLList);
    }
    else if (value is XML)
    {
        var xl:XMLList = new XMLList();
        xl += value;
        collection = new XMLListCollection(xl);
    }
    else
    {
        // convert it to an array containing this one item
        var tmp:Array = [];
        if (value != null)
            tmp.push(value);
        collection = new ArrayCollection(tmp);
    }
    // get an iterator for the displaying rows.  The CollectionView's
    // main iterator is left unchanged so folks can use old DataSelector
    // methods if they want to
    iterator = collection.createCursor();
    collectionIterator = collection.createCursor(); //IViewCursor(collection);
    // trace("ListBase added change listener");
    collection.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, collectionChangeHandler, false, 0, true);

    clearSelectionData();

    var event:CollectionEvent = new CollectionEvent(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE);
    event.kind = CollectionEventKind.RESET;
    collectionChangeHandler(event);
    dispatchEvent(event);

    itemsNeedMeasurement = true;
    invalidateProperties();
    invalidateSize();
    invalidateDisplayList();
}
```

So take a look at line:

```
    collection.addEventListener(CollectionEvent.COLLECTION_CHANGE, collectionChangeHandler, false, 0, true);
```

Comment: This does get rid of the compiler warning but doesn't change the behaviour I described above (or explain it).